# How to get this property value in my java code?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm learning Java and sometimes I have some problem to retrieve the information I need from objects...

When I debug my code I can see in targetFile, a path property but I don't know how to get it in my code.

This is a screenshot:
[image: ide debug view]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1395651483.png))</sub>

This is my complete code:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import com.github.axet.wget.WGet;
import com.github.axet.wget.info.DownloadInfo;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        nodejs();

    }

    public static void nodejs() throws IOException {

        // Scrap the download url.
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://nodejs.org/download").get();
        Element link = doc.select("div.interior:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)").first();
        String url = link.attr("abs:href");

        // Print the download url.
        System.out.println(url);

        // Download file via the scraped url.
        URL download = new URL(url);
        File target = new File("/home/lan/Desktop/");
        WGet w = new WGet(download, target);
        w.download();

        // Get the targetFile property
        // ???

    }

}
```

How can I get this value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get filePath from a WGet object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590762/how-to-get-filepath-from-a-wget-object-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your code but the field you are interested in may be encapsulated and thus not accessible in your code, but the debugger can see it at runtime :)

Update:
https://github.com/axet/wget/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/axet/wget/WGet.java

The field is default package, you can only access it from within the package.
This can be frustrating at times, but you should ask yourself why the designers of this class decided to hide this field.

Comment: Argh, I used wget because I want to get the fullpath of a downloaded file without forcing the filename like the real wget. What can I do?

Comment: Not sure but a 'quick and dirty' way would be to copy the WGet files and make them your own to modify them, this may depend on the license and how you intend to use your code.

Comment: I have not enough experience in Java ...

Do you know a Java library that would do that? I make a script downloads and installs my favorite software on Windows. And I try some libs from multiple programming languages ​​to do what I want.

Comment: I am afraid you will need more experience in Java, I do not have time to explain it all.